# How to detect if menu button was pressed using sl4a?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

Is there a way to detect if the 'menu/settings' button has been pressed on an Android phone using [sl4a](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)?

I was looking through the [API reference](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference), and it looks like the 'Events' section is what I need, but it doesn't specify anything about either the menu, home, search, or back buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the UIFacade to add items to menus, which will allow you to set up the events. You use the Events Facade to handle them.